# Android error : close() was never explicitly called on database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

not sure what's wrong,
I had the database working on one table when I tried to add more tables and it said that the new tables had been set up.

the activity is sent an enum which tells it what type of location to look at ie what table to address

this is the class the handles the sql

```
package com.android.TestApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class Location extends Activity{

public static final String KEY_SHOPROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_SHOPNAME = "shop_name";
public static final String KEY_SHOPADDRESS = "shop_address";
public static final String KEY_SHOPDESCRIPTION = "shop_description";
public static final String KEY_SHOPPOST = "shop_post";
public static final String KEY_SHOPRATE = "shop_rate";
public boolean ISNOT = false;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "NewLocationDataBase";
private static final String DATABASE_SHOPTABLE = "shop_table";
private static final String DATABASE_CAFETABLE = "cafe_table";
private static final String DATABASE_RESTURANTTABLE ="resturant_table";
private static final String DATABASE_HOTELTABLE = "hotel_table";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper theHelper;
private final Context theContext;
private SQLiteDatabase theDataBase;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_SHOPTABLE + " ("+
            KEY_SHOPROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_SHOPNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_SHOPADDRESS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_SHOPDESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_SHOPPOST + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_SHOPRATE + " INTEGER);"
            );

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_CAFETABLE + " (" +
                KEY_SHOPROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_SHOPNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SHOPADDRESS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SHOPDESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SHOPPOST + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SHOPRATE + " INTEGER);"
                );

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_RESTURANTTABLE + " (" +
                KEY_SHOPROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_SHOPNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SHOPADDRESS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SHOPDESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SHOPPOST + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SHOPRATE + " INTEGER);"
                );

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_HOTELTABLE + " (" +
                KEY_SHOPROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_SHOPNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SHOPADDRESS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SHOPDESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SHOPPOST + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SHOPRATE + " INTEGER);"
                );

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_SHOPTABLE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_CAFETABLE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_RESTURANTTABLE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_HOTELTABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public Location(Context c){
    theContext = c;
}

public void createEntry(LocationType type, String name, String address, String description,
        String post, int rate) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_SHOPNAME, name);
    cv.put(KEY_SHOPADDRESS, address);
    cv.put(KEY_SHOPDESCRIPTION, description);
    cv.put(KEY_SHOPPOST, post);
    cv.put(KEY_SHOPRATE, rate);
    switch(type){
    case shop:
        theDataBase.insert(DATABASE_SHOPTABLE, null, cv);
    }
}

public Location writeOpen() throws SQLException{
    theHelper = new DbHelper(theContext);
    theDataBase = theHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public Location readOpen(){
    theHelper = new DbHelper(theContext);
    theDataBase = theHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void writeClose(){
    if(theHelper!=null){
        theHelper.close();
    }
}
public void readClose(){
    if(theHelper!=null){
        theHelper.close();
    }
}


public boolean isEmpty(LocationType type){
    String [] data = {KEY_SHOPNAME};
    Cursor c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_SHOPTABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
    int size = 0;
    switch(type){
    case shop:
        c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_SHOPTABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
    case cafe:
        c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_CAFETABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
    case resturant:
        c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_RESTURANTTABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
    size = 0;
    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        size = size+1;
    }
    if(size ==0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

public String [] getNames(LocationType type){
    String [] data = {KEY_SHOPNAME};
    int size = 0;
    Cursor c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_SHOPTABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
    switch(type){
    case shop:
        c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_SHOPTABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
        size = 0;
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            size = size+1;
        }
    case cafe:
        c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_CAFETABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
        size = 0;
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            size = size+1;
        }
    case resturant:
        c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_RESTURANTTABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
        size = 0;
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            size = size+1;
        }
    }

    String [] Names = new String [size];
    String name = "";
    int nameIndex = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SHOPNAME);
    int index = 0;
    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        name = c.getString(nameIndex);
        Names[index] = name;
        index = index+1;
    }
    return Names;
}

public String [] getDescription(LocationType type){
    String [] data = {KEY_SHOPDESCRIPTION};
    Cursor c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_SHOPTABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
    int size = 0;
    switch(type){
    case shop:
        c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_SHOPTABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        size = size+1;
        }
    case cafe:
        c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_CAFETABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
        size = 0;
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            size = size+1;
        }
    case resturant:
        c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_RESTURANTTABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
        size = 0;
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            size = size+1;
        }
    }

    String [] Descriptions = new String [size];
    String desc = "";
    int descIndex = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SHOPDESCRIPTION);
    int index = 0;
    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        desc = c.getString(descIndex);
        Descriptions[index] = desc;
        index = index+1;
    }
    return Descriptions;
}

public String [] getAddress(LocationType type){
    String [] data = {KEY_SHOPADDRESS};
    Cursor c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_SHOPTABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
    int size = 0;
    switch(type){
    case shop:
        c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_SHOPTABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            size = size+1;
        }
    case cafe:
        c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_CAFETABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
        size = 0;
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            size = size+1;
        }
    case resturant:
        c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_RESTURANTTABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
        size = 0;
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            size = size+1;
        }
    }

    String [] Address = new String [size];
    String address = "";
    int addressIndex = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SHOPADDRESS);
    int index = 0;
    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        address = c.getString(addressIndex);
        Address[index] = address;
        index = index+1;
    }
    return Address;
}

public String [] getPost(LocationType type){

    String [] data = {KEY_SHOPPOST};
    Cursor c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_SHOPTABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
    int size = 0;
    switch(type){
    case shop:
        c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_SHOPTABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            size = size+1;
        }
    case cafe:
        c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_CAFETABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
        size = 0;
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            size = size+1;
        }
    case resturant:
        c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_RESTURANTTABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
        size = 0;
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            size = size+1;
        }
    }

    String [] Post = new String [size];
    String post = "";
    int addressIndex = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SHOPPOST);
    int index = 0;
    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        post = c.getString(addressIndex);
        Post[index] = post;
        index = index+1;
    }
    return Post;
}


public String [] getRow(LocationType type){

    String [] data = {KEY_SHOPROWID};
    Cursor c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_SHOPTABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
    int size = 0;
    switch(type){
    case shop:
        c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_SHOPTABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            size = size+1;
        }
    case cafe:
        c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_CAFETABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
        size = 0;
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            size = size+1;
        }
    case resturant:
        c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_RESTURANTTABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
        size = 0;
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            size = size+1;
        }
    }

    String [] Post = new String [size];
    String post = "";
    int addressIndex = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SHOPROWID);
    int index = 0;
    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        post = c.getString(addressIndex);
        Post[index] = post;
        index = index+1;
    }
    return Post;
}

public int [] getRate(LocationType type){
    String [] data = {KEY_SHOPRATE};
    Cursor c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_SHOPTABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
    int size = 0;
    switch(type){
    case shop:
        c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_SHOPTABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            size = size+1;
        }
    case cafe:
        c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_CAFETABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
        size = 0;
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            size = size+1;
        }
    case resturant:
        c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_RESTURANTTABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
        size = 0;
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            size = size+1;
        }
    }
    int [] rate = new int [size];
    int Rate = 0;
    int addressIndex = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SHOPRATE);
    int index = 0;
    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        Rate = c.getInt(addressIndex);
        rate[index] = Rate;
        index = index+1;
    }
    return rate;
}

public void updateEntry(String index, LocationType type, String nameNew,
        String addressNew, String descriptionNew, String postNew) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_SHOPNAME, nameNew);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_SHOPADDRESS, addressNew);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_SHOPDESCRIPTION, descriptionNew);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_SHOPPOST, postNew);
    switch(type){
    case shop:
        theDataBase.update(DATABASE_SHOPTABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_SHOPROWID + "=" + index, null);
    case cafe:
        theDataBase.update(DATABASE_CAFETABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_SHOPROWID + "=" + index, null);
    case resturant:
        theDataBase.update(DATABASE_RESTURANTTABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_SHOPROWID + "=" + index, null);
    }


}

public int getSize(LocationType type) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String [] data = {KEY_SHOPPOST};
    int size = 0;
    Cursor c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_CAFETABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
    switch(type){
    case shop:
        c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_SHOPTABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
    case cafe:
        c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_CAFETABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
    case resturant:
        c = theDataBase.query(DATABASE_RESTURANTTABLE, data, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
    size = 0;
    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        size = size+1;
    }

    return size;
}

public void removeEntry(String rowId, LocationType type) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(type){
    case shop:
        theDataBase.delete(DATABASE_SHOPTABLE, KEY_SHOPROWID + "=" + rowId, null);

    }

}

public void setRating(String row, LocationType type, int newRating) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cvnewRate = new ContentValues();
    cvnewRate.put(KEY_SHOPRATE,newRating );
    switch(type){
    case shop:
        theDataBase.update(DATABASE_SHOPTABLE, cvnewRate, KEY_SHOPROWID + "=" + row, null);
    }


}
```

this is the activity

```
package com.android.TestApp;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

 public class ShowActivity extends ListActivity {

protected LocationType Type = LocationType.shop;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



  try{


      Location test = new Location(this);   
      if(test.isEmpty(Type)){
          switch(Type){
          case shop:
              String [] Names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shopName);
              String [] Description = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shop_descrt);
              String [] Address =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shop_address);
              String [] Post =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shop_post);
              int [] Rate = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.shop_rate);

              for(int i = 0; Names.length >i; i++){
                Location starting = new Location(this);
                starting.writeOpen();
                starting.createEntry(Type, Names[i], Address[i], Description[i], Post[i], Rate[i]);
                starting.writeClose();
              }

          case cafe:
              String [] cafeNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cafeName);
              String [] cafeDescription = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cafe_descrt);
              String [] cafeAddress =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cafe_address);
              String [] cafePost =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cafe_post);
              int [] cafeRate = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.cafe_rate);

              for(int i = 0; cafeNames.length >i; i++){
                Location starting = new Location(this);
                starting.writeOpen();
                starting.createEntry(Type, cafeNames[i], cafeAddress[i], cafeDescription[i], cafePost[i], cafeRate[i]);
                starting.writeClose();
              }
          case resturant:
              String [] resturantNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.resturantName);
              String [] resturantDescription = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.resturant_desct);
              String [] resturantAddress =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.resturant_address);
              String [] resturantPost =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.resturant_post);
              int [] resturantRate = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.resturant_rate);

              for(int i = 0; resturantNames.length >i; i++){
                Location starting = new Location(this);
                starting.writeOpen();
                starting.createEntry(Type, resturantNames[i], resturantAddress[i], resturantDescription[i], resturantPost[i], resturantRate[i]);
                starting.writeClose();
              }

          case hotel:
              String [] hotelNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shopName);
              String [] hotelDescription = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shop_descrt);
              String [] hotelAddress =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shop_address);
              String [] hotelPost =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shop_post);
              int [] hotelRate = {2,3,3,5,1};

              for(int i = 0; hotelNames.length >i; i++){
                Location starting = new Location(this);
                starting.writeOpen();
                starting.createEntry(Type, hotelNames[i], hotelAddress[i], hotelDescription[i], hotelPost[i], hotelRate[i]);
                starting.writeClose();
              }
          }

      }
  }catch(Exception e){
        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        String error = e.toString();
        d.setTitle("the Database is not set up sorry set up");
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(error);
        d.setContentView(tv);
        d.show();
  }


  try{

          Location Table = new Location(this);
          Table.readOpen();
          String [] name= Table.getNames(Type);
          Table.readClose();

      ListView ln = getListView();  
      setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listitem, name));

      ln.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

      ln.setOnItemClickListener((new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {

                  int index = (int) (id);

                  Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Layout.class);
                  intent.putExtra("index", index);
                  intent.putExtra("type", Type);
                  startActivityForResult(intent,0);
                  }

      }));

  }catch(Exception e){
        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        String error = e.toString();
        d.setTitle("could not display info");
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(error);
        d.setContentView(tv);
        d.show();
  }
}
```

}

EDIT 1:
realised that i wasnt calling writeClose() on test atthe start and that i could not call onDestroy with the listActivity, so i created a buffer activity that does the check test.isEmpty(), now works again for just cases of shop,

think there is a problem in the code of Location in the oncreate or with this

```
        Location test = new Location(this);
  try{

      test.writeOpen();
      if(test.isEmpty(Type)){
          switch(Type){
          case 1:
              String [] Names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shopName);
              String [] Description = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shop_descrt);
              String [] Address =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shop_address);
              String [] Post =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shop_post);
              int [] Rate = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.shop_rate);

              for(int i = 0; Names.length >i; i++){
                Location starting = new Location(this);
                starting.writeOpen();
                starting.createEntry(Type, Names[i], Address[i], Description[i], Post[i], Rate[i]);
                starting.writeClose();
              }

         // case 2:
            //  String [] cafeNames =          getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cafeName);
     //               String [] cafeDescription = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cafe_descrt);
    //                String [] cafeAddress =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cafe_address);
    //                String [] cafePost =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cafe_post);
    //                int [] cafeRate = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.cafe_rate);
    //                
    //                for(int i = 0; cafeNames.length >i; i++){
    //                  Location starting = new  Location(this);
    //                  starting.writeOpen();
    //                  starting.createEntry(Type, cafeNames[i], cafeAddress[i], cafeDescription[i], cafePost[i], cafeRate[i]);
    //                  starting.writeClose();
    //                }
     //           case 3:
    //                String [] resturantNames =   getResources().getStringArray(R.array.resturantName);
    //                String [] resturantDescription = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.resturant_desct);
    //                String [] resturantAddress =   getResources().getStringArray(R.array.resturant_address);
    //                String [] resturantPost =   getResources().getStringArray(R.array.resturant_post);
    //                int [] resturantRate =  getResources().getIntArray(R.array.resturant_rate);
    //                
    //                for(int i = 0; resturantNames.length >i;   i++){
    //                  Location starting = new Location(this);
    //                  starting.writeOpen();
    //                  starting.createEntry(Type, resturantNames[i], resturantAddress[i], resturantDescription[i], resturantPost[i], resturantRate[i]);
    //                  starting.writeClose();
    //                }

         // case hotel:
            //  String [] hotelNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shopName);
            //  String [] hotelDescription = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shop_descrt);
             // String [] hotelAddress =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shop_address);
            //  String [] hotelPost =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shop_post);
            //  int [] hotelRate = {2,3,3,5,1};

            //  for(int i = 0; hotelNames.length >i; i++){
            //  Location starting = new Location(this);
            //  starting.writeOpen();
            //  starting.createEntry(Type, hotelNames[i], hotelAddress[i], hotelDescription[i], hotelPost[i], hotelRate[i]);
            //  starting.writeClose();
             // }
          }

      }
      test.writeClose();
  }catch(Exception e){
        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        String error = e.toString();
        d.setTitle("the Database is not set up sorry set up");
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(error);
        d.setContentView(tv);
        d.show();
  }
  test.writeClose();
```

`

Answer (score 0):

After using your db adapter instance you need to call the close method on it explicitly.

```
theHelper.close();
```

That should help.

Comment: i do i call close() on the Location object, this calls either read close or writeclose depending on which i called which is declared in the Location (SQl file) this calls close on theHelper

Comment: you need to call it inside your readClose and writeClose functions since its not a static variable.

Comment: your right found that along with other mistakes i had made, including not putting breaks into switch sections of my code, cheers, will post the fixes tomorrow in case anyone does what i did

Answer (score 0):

In your class that handles the SQL datbase create a public method like this..

```
public void close(){
theDatabse.close();
}
```

And in your code where you use the Databse make sure you call

```
 theHelper.close();
```

when you are finished accessing the database or you are in your onDestroy();

Comment: i do i call close() on the Location object, this calls either read close or writeclose depending on which i called which is declared in the Location (SQl file) this calls close on theHelper